# jQuery timer in meta refresh redirect page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to redirect users to a different page after 12 seconds and I do this with i.e code. However I’d like to show them a simple countdown in any `div` so they know that this is about to happen in 12 (11, 10, 9….1, 0) seconds

This will need to be written with jQuery. Thanks

```
<meta content="120; url=http://www.example.com" http-equiv="refresh" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this instead:

```
<div id="counter">12</div>

<script>
    ​var count = 12;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (--count < 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
        }
        $("#counter").text(count);
    }, 1000);​
</script>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PeHFc/